# Printing last 10 entries in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

So I'm working on a website that has a list of novels in a database with some basic info about them. I'd like to make a table of the most recent additions to the database. I'm using PHP and SQL and this is what I've got so far.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = "novels";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Select ten most recent entries
SELECT `N_ID`, `NAME`, `DATE_RELEASED`, `GENRES` FROM basic_info ORDER BY N_ID DESC LIMIT 10
?>
```

I"m new to PHP And SQL so what I can gather is that I've made a connection to the database and have pulled the information from the latest 10 entries. Now I'm just not sure how to print them.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Drew don't waste your breath; this one's a *fly-by-night*.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.3) if you can. Also you could use lower case for your columns to avoid case sensitivity issues.
You have to "wrap" your `SELECT` query in a variable (e.g. `$sql`) to be able to pass it in your php code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = "novels";

try {
    //Make your connection handler to your database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$database, $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

    $sql = "SELECT `N_ID`, `NAME`, `DATE_RELEASED`, `GENRES` FROM basic_info ORDER BY N_ID DESC LIMIT 10";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    //Execute the query
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    //Fetch the results
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<p>'.$row['NAME'].'</p>';
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to start from there because he already uses mysqli and i think PDO wins.

Comment: Hm, where is it? It' s running normally on localhost (with and without ; in $sql).